# Getting "parent" `std::tuple` from "children" item pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, tuples, c++14, memory-layout

```
struct Apple { };
struct Banana { };
struct Peach { };

using FruitTuple = std::tuple<Apple, Banana, Peach>;

template<typename TTuple, typename TItem>
TTuple& getParentTuple(TItem* mItemPtr)
{
    // <static assert that the tuple item types are unique>
    // ...?
}

int main()
{
    FruitTuple ft;

    // I know these pointers point to objects inside a `FruitTuple`...
    Apple* ptrApple{&std::get<0>(ft)};
    Banana* ptrBanana{&std::get<1>(ft)};
    Peach* ptrPeach{&std::get<2>(ft)};

    // ...is there a way to get the `FruitTuple` they belong to?
    auto& ftFromA(getParentTuple<FruitTuple>(ptrApple));
    auto& ftFromB(getParentTuple<FruitTuple>(ptrBanana));
    auto& ftFromP(getParentTuple<FruitTuple>(ptrPeach));

    assert(&ftFromA == &ftFromB);
    assert(&ftFromB == &ftFromP);
    assert(&ftFromA == &ftFromP);

    return 0;
}
```

How can `getParentTuple<TTuple, TItem>` be implemented in a **standard-compliant** and **non-architecture-dependent** way?

Comment: Can it be assumed that your tuple does not contain multiple instances of the same type?

Comment: I don't think std::stuple gives you enough guarantees on memory layout to do this is an implementation-independant way.

Comment: It is questionable already whether you can go from a subobject of a struct (with, say, standard layout) to the enclosing struct object. While things like the C++ object model, the standard-layout guarantees, and `offsetof` heavily hint that you can, the Standard is just shy of saying that you are allowed to e.g. perform pointer arithmetic on the underlying bytes of the object, which you will definitively need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible.

Edit:

I do not think there is anything in the standard that prevents a compliant tuple implementation from allocating the elements individually on the heap.

The elements' memory location, then, would not allow any inference that results in the tuple object's location.

The only thing that you can do is to extend your element classes to also contain a back pointer to the tuple that you then fill in after placing your elements in the tuple.

Comment: I do not care about that particular case. Assume the user is always sure that the pointer comes from inside a tuple.

Comment: The preceding comment was in response to an earlier version of my answer, which addressed a case where the user could ask for the containing tuple of an object that did not actually live inside a tuple. Because of this comment I have updated the answer to no longer address only this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

The following is code that should work with common implementations, but I'm pretty sure that it is not standard compliant, because it makes assumptions that the memory layout of the tuple is determinstic.

In a comment you said you don't care about that case, so here you go:

```
template<typename TTuple, typename TItem>
TTuple& getParentTuple(TItem* mItemPtr)
{
    TTuple dummyTuple;

    // The std::get by type will not compile if types are duplicated, so
    // you do not need a static_assert.
    auto dummyElement = (uintptr_t)&std::get<TItem>(dummyTuple);

    // Calculate the offset of the element to the tuple base address.
    auto offset = dummyElement - (uintptr_t)&dummyTuple;

    // Subtract that offset from the passed element pointer.
    return *(TTuple*)((uintptr_t)mItemPtr - offset);
}
```

Note that this constructs the tuple once, which may have unwanted side effects or performance impacts in some cases. I'm not sure if there is a compile time variant of this.